# How to create buffer gate with Vivado Schematic?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, vivado

I am learning Verilog with Vivado for the first time. I am trying to create simple buffer gate with it.

Here is the code I've tried. The first one is Design Source file with name 'inv.v'.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module inv(
    input a,
    output x
    );
    
IBUF buffer(x, a);

endmodule
```

This code does create buffer gate, but it creates 2 of them.

[image]

I've also tried the following code.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module inv(
    input a,
    output x
    );
    
assign x = a;

endmodule
```

However, this creates nothing. What I want is to create only one buffer gate, which is shown in above image. Does anyone know how?

p.s. I am using Vivado 2017.3 HLx Edition.

Answer (score 0):

`IBUF` and `OBUF` are IO buffers: one drives into the logic array from the input pin; the other drives the output pin from the logic array. These are put in by the tool, because they are necessary for electrical reasons (ie reasons of voltage, current etc rather than reasons of boolean arithmetic).

This is why you are struggling to put in your own buffer. A buffer has no function at the boolean level, it is only necessary for electrical reasons. Your Verilog does not concern itself with such detail: such things are added automatically by logic synthesis/layout tools should they feel they are necessary for these electrical reasons (eg to drive a long track or to drive many inputs).

If you want to try something basic to see how your Verilog gets turned into (ie synthesised to) real gates, you'll need to try something that has some function at the boolean level, for example an AND gate. Or, if you want to make it as basic as possible, an invertor.

Comment: So, the reason why I am struggling is that a buffer has no function at the boolean level?

Comment: Yes. It is an electrical component.

Answer (score 0):

See the 7-series libraries guide for more info on ibuf & obuf primitives.
https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2018_3/ug953-vivado-7series-libraries.pdf
Here is a quote from around page 341 of the file at the link.

"In general, IBUFs are inferred by the synthesis tool for top-level input ports to the design, so it is not necessary to specify them in the source code. However, if desired, they can be manually instantiated by copying the code from the appropriate Libraries Guide HDL template and it into the top-level of your code.

Your first example is the instantiation referred to in the libraries guide. For your second example, there is no component instance and Vivado determined no buffer is needed.